# Facebook make a friend request on iOS / API call

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any API call that I can use in order to send a friend request ?
I have seen some applications that allow you to do that, so I have been wondering
how that has been achieved. I can't find anything useful in the documentation.

(all the answers I found are quite old)

Comment: Not an API call (of course not, because that would open the door for all kinds of abuse), but there is the [friend request dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) that you can use.

Comment: Well that's a shame, as the facebook UI does not really fit my app UI

Comment: I used that call anyway just to try it out, how do I bypass the login screen if I already have the user's access token ?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the presentDialogModally methods in [FBWebDialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBWebDialogs/) and pass it the session and @"friends" as the dialog param.

Comment: That requires facebook SDK and I am using the native ios6/7 support for Facebook.